# QGIS Field Sequential Numbering with ordering rule from SW to NE

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator, numbering, sequential

How could I use the $Rownum tool to get sequential number for a field to make sure the southernmost and westernmost point is 1 and the following numbers follow this rule set (where South is first and West is second importance). For example, when I use $Rownum I have this output:

[image]

But What I want is this output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I have found so far is to use the plugin `Sort and Number`. First get latitude and longitude for each point using `Add Geometry Attributes` then use the plugin. Input ycoord as 1st field and xcoord as 2nd field. This will had a column with the row number.